# Uploading file to remote server, but file not found out there

Tags: android

I used this code to upload a file to local server(wamp server) and it works, but when I change the destination of connection to remote web server the code does not show any error and the process is going well but I could not find the file in the server.
Please help me..

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


     String fileName = sourceFileUri;

     HttpURLConnection conn = null;
     DataOutputStream dos = null; 
     String lineEnd = "\r\n";
     String twoHyphens = "--";
     String boundary = "*****";
     int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
     byte[] buffer;
     int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
     File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

     if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

          dialog1.dismiss();

          Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist");

          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  Toast.makeText(UploadAssignment.this, "Source File not exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          });

          return 0;

     }
     else
     {
          try {

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
              FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
              URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
              // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
              conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs

              conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
              conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
              conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
              conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
              conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
              conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
              conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

              dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

              dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
              dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);


              dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

              // create a buffer of  maximum size
              bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

              bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
              buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

              // read file and write it into form...
              bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

              while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               }

              // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
              dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
              dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

              // Responses from the server (code and message)
              serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
              String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

              Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

              if(serverResponseCode == 200)
              {

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                      public void run() {

                           Toast.makeText(UploadAssignment.this, "File Upload Complete.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           browse.setClickable(false);
                           upload.setClickable(false);


                       }
                   });               
              } 

              //close the streams //
              fileInputStream.close();
              dos.flush();
              dos.close();

          }
          catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

             dialog1.dismiss(); 
             ex.printStackTrace();

             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {

                     Toast.makeText(UploadAssignment.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             });

             Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
         } 
          catch (Exception e) {

             dialog1.dismiss(); 
             e.printStackTrace();

             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {

                     Toast.makeText(UploadAssignment.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             });
             Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e); 
         }
         dialog1.dismiss();      
         return serverResponseCode;

     } // End else block

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Below function to upload file in server,

```
private void doFileUpload() {

    File file1 = new File(selectedPath1);
    File file2 = new File(selectedPath2);
    File file3 = new File(selectedPath3);
    File file4 = new File(selectedPath4);
    String urlString = "your server link/folder_name/filename.php";

    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
        FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1);
        FileBody bin2 = new FileBody(file2);
        FileBody bin3 = new FileBody(file3);
        FileBody bin4 = new FileBody(file4);
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile1", bin1);
        reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile2", bin2);
        reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile3", bin3);
        reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile4", bin4);
        reqEntity.addPart("user", new StringBody("User"));
        post.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        resEntity = response.getEntity();
        final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        if (resEntity != null) {
            Log.i("RESPONSE", response_str);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Upload Complete. Check the server uploads directory.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working. When I run the code it give me an exception could not found org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody

Comment: @user2287444 you have to include external jar files in to your project for uploading multiple files to server.